# Wild card redirection on the DNS level for domain

Tags: redirect, dns, namecheap

Let's say I have domain `long_domain_name.tld` and want to use `short.tld` as a short domain name for (alias) `long_domain_name.tld`, but in my DNS settings when I set `URL REDIRECT` record for `short.tld` to redirect to `long_domain_name.tld`: URLs like `short.tld/x/y` will redirect to `long_domain_name.tld` but I want to redirect to `long_domain_name.tld/x/y`.

#### Question:

How can I set `short.tld/*` to redirect to `long_domain_name.tld/*` **on the DNS level**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as DNS level redirection. Some DNS hosting providers offer this but that is essentially a HTTP web server/app that responds with redirect, so the answer is very specific to the DNS provider and should be searched for in their documentation or with their support.

That being said :), in case of namecheap it seems that you need to add a forward slash "/" in the end of your destination URL:

> Once you add this special symbol after `http://destination.tld` >>
>   `http://destination.tld/` , the URL `domain.tld/xyz.html` or
>   `domain.tld/home` will redirect the users to
>   `http://destination.tld/xyz.html` or `http://destination.tld/home`
>   respectively (in case the sub-folder (`/xyz.html` or `/home`) exists
>   on `destination.tld`).
>
> All values that are put into the original URL (domain.tld/anything)
>   will be included in the destination address and applied in the results
>   (`http://destination.tld/anything`).

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10043/2237/url-redirect-with-parameters#specificpage